# news: Different settings via typoscript for multiple listviews on one page

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Using the extension news I implemented three list views on one page with different `colPos`. Now I need to make some different settings for each list view. I would prefer doing this via TypoScript.
Is there a solution for this?

Many thanks and best regards!

Comment: All settings could be of type *stdWrap*. With stdWrap, you could use any cObject including *CASE*, *override* and/or *if*. For a few settings, this might work, for many settings, it could get confusing.
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Reference/TypoScript/GeneralSettings.html?highlight=stdwrap#usestdwrap

Comment: Maybe *templateLayouts* can also solve your use-case. Instead of settings via TS, maybe some could be hard-coded in the template. (https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Reference/TsConfig/General.html#templatelayouts)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends which settings you need. One easy solution could be something like thins

```
plugin.tx_news.settings {
  mainCol {
    setting = abc
  }
  leftCol {
   setting = def
  }
}
```

and in the fluid templates

```html
<f:if condition="{contentObjectData.colPos} == 3">
  <f:then><f:variable name="mySettings">{settings.mainCol}</f:then>
  <f:else><f:variable name="mySettings">{settings.leftCol}</f:else>
</f:if>
<f:render section="list" arguments="{_all}" />
<f:section name="list">
... do your stuff here
{mySettings -> f:debug(inline:1)}
</f:section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I understand how the variable mySettings is set, but as a beginner of typo3 I don’t understand how the settings are given to the plugin: Via {mySettings -> f:debug(in-line:1)}. Or is this line just set for debugging? I tried to research, but I didn’t get the trick.

Comment: <f:variable name="mySettings">123</f:variable> is just a vh which sets a variable which can be later used to a value. the settings.mainCol is set in TS and everything with settings as previews is added to the fluid template automatically

Comment: feel free to ask more, maybe in slack as it is sometimes a bit easier to support

Comment: Many thanks for your support again! But I'm still struggling ... In theory I understand your solution, but obviously I still make mistakes. To make things easier I just tried to set the variable mySettings `<f:variable name="mySettings">{settings}</f:variable>` and set `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`. Unfortunatley mySettings is NULL. It seems that {settings} has no content. I pasted the code in the partial which renders the maincontent of my sitepackage.